# python list classification base on inside values

Tags: python

`mylist = [1, 1,2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15,28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27]`
I wish to make the list become:
`mylist = [[1, 1],[2, 2, 2], [15, 15, 15, 15],[28], [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [27, 27, 27]]`
what is the best way to do it? can someone help me please

Comment: Please add some code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15, 28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27]
c = Counter(mylist)
mylist = []
for key in c:
    mylist.append([key]*c[key])
print(mylist)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [15, 15, 15, 15], [28], [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [27, 27, 27]]
```

OR

```
mylist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15, 28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27, 1, 1, 1, 1]
temp = []
value=mylist[0]
count = 0
for item in mylist:
    if(item==value):
        count+=1
    else:
        temp.append([value]*count)
        value=item
        count=1
temp.append([value]*count)
mylist = temp.copy()
print(mylist)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [15, 15, 15, 15], [28], [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [27, 27, 27], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. what if in this case ```mylist = [1, 1,2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15,28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27,1,1,1,1,]``` I wish it become ```mylist = [[1, 1],[2, 2, 2], [15, 15, 15, 15],[28], [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [27, 27, 27],[1,1,1,1]]```

Comment: @holaling I have modified the code, you can check the second part for your query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way, but this is reliable!

```
mylist = [1, 1,2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15,28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27]
helper = []
for x in set(mylist):
    helper.append([x for y in range(mylist.count(x))])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [15, 15, 15, 15], [21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21], [27, 27, 27], [28]]
```

Explanation:
With the set() function, every duplicate gets removed from the list. So you have a set with all distinct number that are contained in the list. No you loop through the numbers `for x in set(mylist):` and make a list for each one, containing the number as often as the original list did. You can check the number of occurrences with the count() function.

Comment: Please explain the code so that the person who asked can understand

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15,28, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 27, 27, 27]
mylist.sort()#Sorting it in order
newList = []
numbersAdded = []
for number in mylist:#Looping through each
   if number not in numbersAdded:#If the number has not already been added, we create a newList
      newList.append([number])
   else:
      newList[(newList.length-1)].append(number)#Since the list is in order, the number we get has its list in the last. We add it to that
print(newList)
```

Comment: Have you tested whether this gives the desired output :) ?